# How to create javascript sequential animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, snap.svg

I'm looking for a way that allow me to create a sequential animation with Javascript...
Here is my try:

```
var b = Snap("#backgroundSvg"); //Initilizing Snap.svg
Snap.load("../img/landscape.svg", function(f){ //Loading the image
 b.append(f); //Appending it to the DOM
 polygon = f.selectAll("polygon"); //Selecting all the polygon elements
 polygon.attr({"fill-opacity": 0}); //Make them transparent
 polygon.forEach(function(e){ //Trying to make a sequential animation
   setTimeout(function (){
     e.animate({ 
       "fill-opacity":1
     }, 800, mina.easein);
   },200);
 });
});
```

But when I run that the result is an easy, boring, animation of that image... 
How could I do that?

Comment: You could do something a bit like http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframe with the addition of including an element in the storage. If the animations will all be the same, ie scaling the elements up and down in sequence, you could set a varying timeout on the setTimeout call instead of 200. It would naturally be more helpful if there was a jsfiddle as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to rewrite a few bits of the original code, mainly

```
f.selectAll("polygon");
```

to

```
 b.selectAll("polygon"); //as you have now appended the fragment, otherwise it may return empty
```

and use an index i on the forEach loop to adjust the timeout later.

```
polygon.forEach(function(e,i){ //Trying to make a sequential animation
    setTimeout(function (){
       e.animate({ 
          "fill-opacity":1
        }, 800, mina.easein);
    },i*200);
});
```

[here](http://svg.dabbles.info/stackoverflowtest.html) is a test with a different image and using a group, as I don't have your original image to look at, but it should illustrate the above.